Function argument with tree type
I liked to define a function argument type representing a tree with only nodes: 0,1. Every subtree is defined as a list like this:
{node,{subtree1},{subtree2},...}
The definition is recursive. The most basic structures are the root only trees: {0},{1}.

The build-in (experimental) function Tree[ ] is not useful for your purpose?

It's too general for my purposes.

Here is a possible simple implementation:
nodeQ[node_] := MatchQ[node, 0 | 1];
treeQ[tree_] := MatchQ[tree, {_?nodeQ, ___?treeQ}];

f[tree_?treeQ] := tree
f[___] := $Failed


f[{0}]
(* {0} *)

f[{3}]
(* $Failed *)

f[{0, {1}}]
(* {0, {1}} *)

f[{0, 1, 2}]
(* $Failed *)

f[{0, {1}, {0, {1, {0, {1}}}}}]
(* {0, {1}, {0, {1, {0, {1}}}}} *)

If you really want to have a single pattern, look at How to define a recursive pattern?.

I guessed there is no way to build a pattern. So the function is the best solution. I made a function that is longest than yours. But your solution can be improved this way:
treeQ[tree_] := MatchQ[tree, {0 | 1, ___?treeQ}]

@GiovanniRusso, I have deliberately separated nodeQ and treeQ, but you can merge them in one, sure. As for the single pattern: Search for recursive patterns.
